# FlickrAPI trouble understanding

Tags: swift, flickr

I have to make an app that has the user place a pin on a map and then pulls pictures from Flickr based off the pin's location. My professor gave us a FlickrAPI file to use but I am having trouble understanding what it is doing.

```
import Foundation

class FlickrAPI: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = FlickrAPI()    // Create a Singleton for the class

var photos: Array<String> = []
var errorLevel = 0

// Flickr Constants
let BASE_URL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
let METHOD_NAME = "flickr.photos.search"
let API_KEY = "<API Key Here>"

func fetchPhotosFromFlickrBasedOn(Latitude lat: Double, Longitude lng: Double, PageToFetch pageToFetch: Int, completion: @escaping (_ error: Int, _ pg: Int, _ pgs: Int) -> Void) {
    // Empty our Photos Array
    photos.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

    // Build Aurgument List
    let methodArguments = [
        "method": METHOD_NAME,
        "api_key": API_KEY,
        "lat": String(format: "%f", lat),
        "lon": String(format: "%f", lng),
        "accuracy": "15",       // Accuracy (Street Level)
        "radius": "1",          // Distance
        "radius_units": "km",   // in Kilometers,
        "safe_search": "1",     // Safe (G Rated),
        "content_type": "1",    // Photos Only
        "per_page": "100",      // Photos per Page
        "page": "\(pageToFetch)",
        "extras": "url_m",      // Return Photo URLs
        "format": "json",       // Request JSON data format
        "nojsoncallback": "1"   // No JSON Callback
    ]

    // Initialize Shared Session
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: BASE_URL + escapeUrlParameters(methodArguments))!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    var page = 0
    var pages = 0

    // Setup Session Handler
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        self.errorLevel = 0  // Initialize Error Level
        if error != nil {
            self.errorLevel = 1  //***** Network Error
        } else {
            // Okay to Parse JSON
            do {
                let parsedResult: AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as AnyObject
                if let photosDictionary = parsedResult.value(forKey: "photos") as? NSDictionary {
                    if let photoArray = photosDictionary.value(forKey: "photo") as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        page = photosDictionary["page"] as! Int
                        pages = photosDictionary["pages"] as! Int
                        for photoDictionary in photoArray {
                            if let photoUrl = photoDictionary["url_m"] as? NSString {
                                let ext = photoUrl.pathExtension
                                let noExt = photoUrl.deletingPathExtension
                                let addThumbDesignation = (noExt + "_q_d") as NSString
                                let thumbUrl = addThumbDesignation.appendingPathExtension(ext)
                                self.photos.append(thumbUrl!)
                            } else {
                                NSLog("***** Could not obtain an Image URL at Index:%d for Owner:%@", self.photos.count, photoDictionary["owner"] as! String)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.errorLevel = 4  //***** No "Photo" Array key present
                    }
                } else {
                    self.errorLevel = 3  //***** No "Photos" Dictionary key present
                }
            } catch {
                self.errorLevel = 2  //***** Parsing Error
            }
            completion(self.errorLevel, page, pages)
        }
    }) 
    task.resume()
}

// Escape URL Parameters
func escapeUrlParameters(_ parms: [String : String]) -> String {
    var urlParms = [String]()
    for (key, value) in parms {
        let escapedValue = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        urlParms += [key + "=" + "\(escapedValue!)"]
    }
    return urlParms.isEmpty ? "" : "?" + urlParms.joined(separator: "&")
}
}
```

In my code I have this function:

```
@IBAction func addPin(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: Map)
    var newCoordinates = Map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: Map)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinates
    Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    flickr.fetchPhotosFromFlickrBasedOn(Latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, Longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude, PageToFetch: 1, completion: {error,pg,pgs in
print("Error: \(error)")
print("Page: \(pg)")
print("Pages: \(pgs)")
})
    //flickr.escapeUrlParameters(<#T##parms: [String : String]##[String : String]#>)
}
```

I understand that the code should be sending json information that I am supposed to use to display the image results on my app but like I said I am having a hard time understanding my professor's code. My main problem is after calling the function it skips everything that needs to run to pull the photos. I am clearly missing what I need to have so that my code will execute what it needs.

Comment: It's not too bad...lemme slap something together

Comment: Now it keeps throwing error 3 at me saying there is no photosDictionary. Man I am confused.

Comment: I'm looking at his code and it look a bit goofy in some spots. JSONSerialization is a crusty way to unpack JSON responses...Codable is a lot easier...I'd rather chew glass than do it the way he's doing it. LOL

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo for this?

Comment: All I wanted was to pull the pictures from Flickr based off gps location and then navigate to a new view where I would display the pictures.

Comment: No git repo should I make one? And I am not the one who made the code for the API my professor did. I would need to make it work with it. My classmates have had better luck.

Comment: I just made a git repo https://github.com/jasonhutch12/FlickrMapProject.git

Comment: You're gonna need to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Ok. I added it. What was it for?

Comment: If its because of the locationManager stuff don't worry about that I was going to scrap it since I don't think I need it.

Comment: Download Postman and put a breakpoint at `url` in the `FlickrAPI` file. When you hit it, do `po url`. Dump the URL in Postman and you'll see you've got an invalid radius parameter. That's what's generating your error. Looks like it's a valid parameter, based on documentation. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html Still tinkering

Comment: Oh... I changed the radius. Was that bad? I figured I would get more results as it was set to 1 before

Comment: Yep. I just changed it to one and it works.

Comment: What about the photos. Are photos being added to the photo array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184846/discussion-between-adrian-and-jason-hutchison).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `radius` parameter you had in `FlickrAPI` specified a radius that was not valid for Flickr's API. It should be something lower than 50. You'll have to play around with to see what the max you can get away with is, if that's the route you want to go.

I would recommend using Postman to test URLs, rather than fiddling around debugging API issues in Xcode. Get your API call-oriented poop in a group before making calls in Xcode. It's a lot easier that way. In this case, just put a breakpoint at wherever the URL is, type `po url` in the debugger, copy the URL into [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) and see what comes back in Postman. API's like Flickr are pretty good at telling you what ****ed up. Also, don't be afraid to look at documentation for stuff. It makes life a lot easier. The documentation for this endpoint is located [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html).

When you get to the completion call, put another breakpoint and type `po photos`. It'll print out an array of strings, which are URLs for the photos.

You probably don't need the location manager or the usage description thing in your info.plist if you're just tapping on the map. Lastly, don't chuck an API key out there in an open forum like GitHub or SO.

Comment: So it should work to where the photo array gets filled so all i need to do is pull them to an image view or something similar to display?

Comment: Yep. I'd use a CocoaPod to do that. There's one called `Kingfisher` which is dirt simple t use. Check GitHub for the repo.

Comment: @JasonHutchison What happened with your final?